# UITextField set placeholder color

Tags: uitextfield, placeholder

I've been mocking about on the internet for a while and found this bit of code:

```
.h
IBOutlet UITextField *TextField;

.m
[TextField setValue:[UIColor lightGrayColor]
                                  forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

It's not working I'm using IOS 6.1 Running in the Simulator. 
Is it because I haven't subclassed the given UITextField?

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as long as you have initialized the UITextField in IB already (or in code). At least it works for me in Xcode 5/iOS 7.